# Модальное диалоговое окно

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как создать модальное диалоговое окно(как окно папки) на html странице, которое можно перемещать свободно по странице?
С чего стоит начать?

Comment: С `<div class="modal"></div>`.

Comment: Изучить функции событий движения мыши